# Running Command as Administrator from a SYSTEM Process

Tags: powershell, registry, system, administrator

So I need to clear a user's run dialog history which I can do perfectly fine with "reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Windows etc..." from an elevated powershell window on the logged in user's machine, but what I'm looking to do is that same command but from a SYSTEM powershell process. I have already used psexec to create a powershell window which runs as SYSTEM, but because you can't just use HKEY_CURRENT_USER as SYSTEM with the same results, I am finding it quite difficult. If I could just run that command but as username\Administrator then I wouldn't have this problem.

Also to note, if I can somehow grab the username of the logged on user (from SYSTEM still) in one line in plain text (with no other output in sight), then I can store the username in a variable and convert that to an SID and use HKEY_USERS instead.

P.S. Don't ask why I'm running powershell as SYSTEM, I know what I'm doing :D

Comment: Have you looked at HKU branch? It contains all the user registries, identified with SID values. Sysinternals has, of course, a tool that translates SIDs to human-readable account names and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

you can use get-process under the system context powershell and filter where explorer.exe process is running, get the account it is running under then use to convert to SID and go through the registry.

Comment: Sorry, could you provide a working example, I'm not sure how to go about this but it definitely sounds like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

something like this assuming only 1 explorer.exe process is running which is the norm on windows client OS.

```
$proc = Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'explorer.exe'"
$owner = Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $proc -MethodName GetOwner
$username = $owner.user
```

$username will contain the user, $owner will also contain domain and a few other things.

to convert to sid

```
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($owner.Domain, $owner.User) 
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]) 
$strSID.Value
```